# Crash with "suspend resume partial function for StoreKitManaer.purchase(_:)"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

There were no crashes in emulator and real device tests, and I do not receive any negative feedback during the application publishing phase. Later, when I download the published application from the market and make an in-app purchase, my application crashes. Crashlytics output is as follows;
`<compiler-generated> - Line 4308224304 (5) suspend resume partial function for StoreKitManaer.purchase(_:) + 4308224304`

The code I wrote is as follows

```
VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(self.products) { product in
                        Button {
                            _ = Task<Void, Never> {
                                do {
                                    try await self.purchase(product)
                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            }
                        } label: {
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    if product.displayName.contains("50") {
                                        Text(appState.langType == 1 ? "50 BKP" : "50 WAIP")
                                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold))
                                    } else if  product.displayName.contains("200") {
                                        Text(appState.langType == 1 ? "200 BKP" : "200 WAIP")
                                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold))
                                    } else {
                                        Text("---")
                                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold))
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(product.displayPrice)
                                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.task {
                do {
                    try await self.loadProducts()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
```

functions for purchasing

```
private func loadProducts() async throws {
        // Products are not returned in the order the ids are requested
        self.products = try await Product.products(for: productIds)
    }
    
    private func purchase(_ product: Product) async throws {
        let result: Product.PurchaseResult = try await product.purchase()
        switch result {
        case let .success(.verified(transaction)):
            // Successful purchase
            self.isPurchase = true
            self.isPurchasePoint = Int(product.displayName)
            var totalCoins = preferences.integer(forKey: "currrent_waip")
            var newTotalCoins = totalCoins + Int(product.displayName)!
            preferences.set(newTotalCoins, forKey: "currrent_waip")
            await transaction.finish()
        case let .success(.unverified(_, error)):
            // Successful purchase but transaction/receipt can't be verified
            // Could be a jailbroken phone
            break
        case .pending:
            // Transaction waiting on SCA (Strong Customer Authentication) or
            // approval from Ask to Buy
            break
        case .userCancelled:
            // ^^^
            break
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
```